# why a list in python can be changed using the a[1] = a[1][0]?

Tags: python, list

(I am a beginner)

Here is a code using concept of list and the question is asking to print out the following result:

```
[1, 'A', 3,] [1, 'A', 3,]
```

as shown in the below screenshot:

[image]

Given that the option being chosen is a correct one.

**What bother me is that why the code in that option works...

especially the code "a[1 ] = a[1 ][0]"

**

I searched in the internet but I have not found a concrete description about it.

Can anyone provide some help?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Useful reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: they are not the same! What I want to know is the chosen code works. I don't know why "a[1] = a[1][0]" works actually

Comment: Then please [edit] to clarify what you still don't understand.

Comment: I have edited. Please see the bold sentence in my post!

Comment: Why wouldn't it? What precise part of it don't you understand? Have you tried running it in a debugger or on e.g. http://pythontutor.com/ or just adding a `print` between the two lines?

Comment: I have edited the post again. The code I don't know is "a[1] = a[1][0]". I have tried and checked all your suggestions but I still don't know why. I spent about an hour on only this line of code but I still couldn't figure out the principle behind...

Answer (score 0):

Because lists are mutable objects in python. You are creating list by declaring

```
 a = [1,2,3]
```

and then declaring that `b = a`, at which point both a and b point to the same list. (note that this does not work with immutable types, such as integers in python).

Comment: Maybe my original question is not that clear. I have just edited it a bit. Sorry about that.

What question is actually, why the following code works?

b[1] = ‘AB’
a[1] = a[1][0]

Comment: Because a[1] points to the newly created 'AB', which itself can be accessed by indexing, which means that a[1][0] points to 'A'.